# What's the mono-space font used on iPad's upcoming Swift Playgrounds app?

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

I was wondering if you guys know the name of the mono-space font on iPad's new coding app "Swift Playgrounds" that's coming out this fall. Here's the url to what the font looks like: http://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the new San Francisco Mono font. It's included in the Xcode 8 beta as the default font as well.